# Novice, confused by primitive web form

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine

Working on Udacity homework, I found myself totally confused. Here's simplified version of my code:

```
import webapp2
form = '''
<h1>Signup</h1>
<form method='post'>
    Username <input type='text' name='username'>%(usr)s<br>
    <br>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
'''

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, usr=''):
        self.response.write(form % {'usr':usr})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        user = self.request.get('username')
        if user:
            self.redirect('/welcome')
        else:
            self.get()

class WelcomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = self.request.get('username')
        self.response.out.write('Welcome, %s' % user)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/welcome', WelcomePage)], debug=True)
```

When I submit username, only 'Welcome,' is being displayed. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `self.redirect('/welcome')` your `self.request.get('username')` data is lost and NOT passed to:

```
class WelcomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = self.request.get('username')
```

and thus you end up with empty username so this is the expected behaviour for the code you provided.

There are many ways to get around that (depending on your requirements) but some are:

- you could display the Welcome message right away without redirects
- instead of POSTing to `/` you could POST directly to `/welcome` (i.e. `<form method='post' action='/welcome'>`) and if the username was empty there then you'd redirect back to the form on `/`
- pass the username as a GET parameter when redirecting, i.e. `self.redirect('/welcome?username=' + user)`
- you could store the username somewhere so it's persistent between the requests (i.e. memcache, session/cookie, ndb, etc).

Comment: I've upvoted you, even when I don't like some of the ways you suggest to get around the issue:

Comment: @mydaemon, sure, those are just quick workarounds for this particular issue but feel free to edit my post to indicate what suggestions shouldn't be used for what reasons

Comment: Sorry @Mihail Russu, my comment was cut when editing; I've noticed you've edited the answer with the redirect adding the username. I don't like suggesting to new developers possible solutions that just mess up the code or they are not the right thing to do, that's it. But the answer has been useful to the op.

Answer (score 0):

as @Mihail Russu noticed, `username` is lost during `self.redirect('/welcome')`. Solution that is most suitable for me is to replace `self.redirect('/welcome')` by `self.redirect('/welcome?username=' + user)`